# My surprise/the surprise

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, possessive-pronouns

> A: I have a surprise for you, Do you want to know what **my** surprise is?
>
> B: Yes
>
> A: Your favorite team won the game

Is the usage of **my** correct? or we must say:

> Do you want to know what **the** surprise is?

Answer (score 1):

It can be both **my surprise** (because I have it) and **your surprise** (because it is for you).

But certainly also **the surprise**, **today's surprise**.

Comment: It can be "my surprise" because I am giving it to you.  It could also be "the BBC's surprise".

Answer (score -3):

If you specifying that " **'I'** have surprise for you." then you don't need to specify "MY surprise". You can just say " Do you want to know?"

Comment: we could say "my surprise" even if the speaker is not a contributor in the surprise ?(I  mean for example the speaker just announced something)

Comment: Generally when I am talking to anyone. I would say " I got a surprise for you. Would you like to know about the surprise?" - Now I am the only one who said the I got a surprise there is no one who said so. If people are around and that person is unsure that time you can that "would you like to know my surprise?" In general one to one talk, text and email we say" Hey I got surprise for you. Would you like to know?"

Comment: Longer and shorter versions of the same thing can both be correct. "Do you want to know what it is?" (for example) would do, but stylistically "Do you want to know what my surprise is" might be preferred, for example for emphasis or suspense. Anyway, it means the answer is wrong.